# Problem accessing Unreal Engine github repository

Tags: github, unreal-engine4

In trying to access the `Unreal Engine` `github` repository (at `https://www.github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine`), I've been getting a 404 error: although the `Epic Games` repository (at `https://www.github.com/EpicGames`) works fine it, strangely, doesn't list the `Unreal Engine` as one of its repositories.  What's going on? Have I got the wrong URL? (I'm signed in to `github`, BTW, but not to `Epic Games`)

Russell

Comment: Could it be because you need an [Epic Games account](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/ue4-on-github)?

Comment: I've installed the `Epic Games Launcher`: would that give me such an account?

Comment: Can you sign in [here](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/) -> `sign in`? This is what is required. If you go through the steps on my first link you should be good to go.

Comment: Well, when I say "sign in" to `Epic Games`, I mean "get an `Epic Games` account". (and, no, your link wouldn't get me there :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to link your GitHub-Account to your Epic Games-Account in order to become a member of the GitHub-organisation, whose members have access to the repository. For more information read [this article](https://www.epicgames.com/help/en-US/epic-accounts-c74/connect-accounts-c110/how-do-i-link-my-unreal-engine-account-with-my-github-account-a3618)

The full steps can be found [here](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/ue4-on-github)